# VBA : While and If then Do functions

Tags: vba

I would like to compare the value form my ComboBox, coded as " & strQ & ", with the values from the first column on page "6 - Liste des Partenaires". The Range "Chapeau_Partenaire" is in A1.

I'm newer in VBA, I don't know how to code the function If then Do. It appears in red in my code. Thank you very much for your help.

```
Public Sub INFO_PROTO(ByRef strQ As String)
Num_Ligne = Range("Chapeau_Partenaire").Row + 1
While Worksheets("6 - Liste des Partenaires").Cells(Num_Ligne, Range("Chapeau_Partenaire").Column) <> ""
if " & strQ & " = Worksheets("6 - Liste des Partenaires").Cells(Num_Ligne, Range("Chapeau_Partenaire").Column)
Then Do
Worksheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi Commercial").Range("Calcul_CMA_Origine") = "1"
Worksheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi Commercial").Range("Calcul_Perf_Contrat_et_Orient") = "1"
Worksheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi Commercial").Range("Calcul_CMA_Perf_An") = "1"
    Else
Worksheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi Commercial").Range("Calcul_CMA_Origine") = "1"
Worksheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi Commercial").Range("Calcul_Perf_Contrat_et_Orient") = "0"
Worksheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi Commercial").Range("Calcul_CMA_Perf_An") = "0"
    End If
    Num_Ligne = Num_Ligne + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need quotes around and you don't need Do.

```vb
Public Sub INFO_PROTO(ByRef strQ As String)
Dim Num_Ligne As Long

    Num_Ligne = Range("Chapeau_Partenaire").Row + 1
    
    While Worksheets("6 - Liste des Partenaires").Cells(Num_Ligne, Range("Chapeau_Partenaire").Column) <> ""
        If strQ = Worksheets("6 - Liste des Partenaires").Cells(Num_Ligne, Range("Chapeau_Partenaire").Column) Then
            Worksheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi Commercial").Range("Calcul_CMA_Origine") = "1"
            Worksheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi Commercial").Range("Calcul_Perf_Contrat_et_Orient") = "1"
            Worksheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi Commercial").Range("Calcul_CMA_Perf_An") = "1"
        Else
            Worksheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi Commercial").Range("Calcul_CMA_Origine") = "1"
            Worksheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi Commercial").Range("Calcul_Perf_Contrat_et_Orient") = "0"
            Worksheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi Commercial").Range("Calcul_CMA_Perf_An") = "0"
        End If
        Num_Ligne = Num_Ligne + 1
    Wend

End Sub
```